# Configure Log4Net for NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

This has got to be a lamer question:

In my test project I am attempting to configure log4net. The following method call gives the error.

BasicConfigurator.Configure();

"type name expected but method found"

What am I overlooking?

Thanks,
 Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops.. I was trying to do this in the wrong context. I added the method call to my test project's constructor and we're good.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a compile time error or runtime error?  Do you have a `using log4net.Config` statement in your class file?  Does it still happen if you change it to reference the full class name?

```
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if linking to blog entries is verboten...

If you are trying to log NHibernate stuff, here is what I do:

[How to show Log4Net info in NUnit (from NHibernate)](http://elegantcode.com/2008/07/29/how-to-show-log4net-info-in-nunit-from-nhibernate/)

I also have a more basic getting started guide here:

[Getting Started with Log4Net](http://elegantcode.com/2007/12/07/getting-started-with-log4net/)